# PostgreSQL 11 and Oracle foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, centos8, oracle-fdw

I have a problem with installing the Oracle foreign data wrapper for PostgreSQL_11 on CENTOS 8.

I have no connection to internet, so I copied all necessary files by SSH, I have installed PostgreSQL 11 and Oracle client, and finally need to install Oracle FWD (oracle_fwd-master.zip). Initially I unzipped and then by instruction below:
ORACLE FDW INSTALLATION:

```
root@user-laptop:~# cd /opt/oracle_fdw/
root@user-laptop:/opt/oracle_fdw# make
root@user-laptop:/opt/oracle_fdw# make install
```

but I got below issue

```
[root@oracle_fdw-master]# make
make: pg_config: Command not found
make: *** No targets.  Stop.**
```

Please help how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

First, never run `make` as user `root`. It will work, but is an unnecessary danger. That is why `mak` mand `make install` are two different steps: the latter typically has to be run by `root`.

Anyway, your problem is that you either didn't install the `postgresql11-devel` package, or `/usr/pgsql-11/bin` is not on your `PATH`.

Verify that the headers and `pg_config` are installed, and try

```
PATH=/usr/pgsql-11/bin:$PATH make
```

Comment: actually now PATH is like this

Comment: is it correct now?       [root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm home]# echo $PATH
/usr/pgsql-11/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: now i have next problem:                                                                       
[root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm oracle_fdw-master]# make
Makefile:20: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/pgsql-11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.

Comment: [root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm user]# rpm -ivh ./postgresql11-devel-11.6-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm
warning: ./postgresql11-devel-11.6-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 442df0f8: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libicu-devel is needed by postgresql11-devel-11.6-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64

Comment: Well, then install the dependency. This forum is about programming, not about installing software. You should [open an issue](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/issues). But first, read the installation instructions carefully.